# Is it possible to use a Predicate in a Java Stream when a specific condition is met?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, predicate

Let's say that I have a method with two predicates: (simplified for clarity)

```
public List<Data> getData(List<OtherData> otherData, String value, String otherValue) {

    Predicate<OtherData> predicate1 = otherData -> otherData.getValue().equals(value))
    Predicate<OtherData> predicate2 = otherData -> otherData.getOtherValue().equals(otherValue))

    return otherData.stream()
        .filter(predicate1.and(predicate2))
        .map(otherData -> Data.of(otherData))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

But let's say that I'd like to change this code so the predicates are created and used dynamically basing on the availibility of `String value` and `String otherValue` - whenever they are `not null`.

I have seen such approach using `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` and `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`, creating a `List<Predicate>` and filling this list using some ifology like

List predicates;
if(value != null) {
predicates.add(//predicate logic here);
}

and using them later in `CriteriaQuery.query.where()`

but this is persistence related stuff, and I would like to do it in a non-persistent context (and without the ifology if possible)

Is this possible?

Comment: Or just write `otherData -> value == null || otherData.getValue().equals(value)` or better (and nullsafe) `otherData -> value == null || Objects.equals(otherData.getValue(), value)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the predicates in the following way: value == null || elementValue.equals(value).

```
Predicate<OtherData> valueNull = v -> Objects.isNull(value);
Predicate<OtherData> predicate1 = valueNull.or(otherData -> otherData.getValue().equals(value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar by using `Stream.reduce`. In a generic way:

```
List<Predicate<T>> predicates = ...
Predicate<T> combined = predicates.stream()
        .reduce(t -> true, Predicate::and);
```